# Posting json data to remote server with http.Post

Tags: json, go

I am stumped on what seems like a very simple problem.

I am receiving a json object from a client. It looks like this:

```
{
    "user": "test@example.com"
}
```

I need to simply pass this on to another part of the api as a POST request. This is what i've got until now:

```
//Decode incomming json
decoder := json.NewDecoder(r.Body)
var user UserInformation
err := decoder.Decode(&user)

if err != nil {
    log.Println(err)
}

jsonUser, _ := json.Marshal(user)

log.Println(string(jsonUser[:])) //Correct output
buffer := bytes.NewBuffer(jsonUser)
log.Println(string(buffer.Bytes()[:])) //Also correct


resp, err := http.Post("http://example.com/api/has_publisher", "application/json", buffer)
if err != nil {
    log.Println(err)
}
```

As I cannot test this program on a live system, I verified the resulting post request with wireshark only to find that the content is missing along with Content-Length being 0. For some reason, http.Post doesn't read from the buffer.

Am i missing something here? I would greatly appreciate if someone could point me in the right direction.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you try *http.Post("http://example.com/api/has_publisher", "application/json", r.Body)* ?

Comment: Same thing happens. No data.

Comment: I mean without any JSON decode/encode stuff. Or can your try to post to a localhost page and see the result rather than wireshark?

Comment: I tried initializing a buffer with a string like so: `buffer := bytes.NewBuffer([]byte("test"))` and it apparently doesn't make a difference. With wireshark, i can see the other requests just fine, with content and all. I'm making the requests with postman. So i don't think it will make a difference...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shouldn`t be the root cause but replace

`buffer := bytes.NewBuffer(jsonUser)`

with

`buffer := bytes.NewReader(jsonUser)`

It is more likely that your test setup is the root cause. I assume you are pointing to a non-existing endpoint. This would result in a failure (TCP SYN fails) before the actual HTTP POST is send.

Check if you can use [mockable.io](http://www.mockable.io) as an alternative to mock your backend.

Comment: Another, even simpler idea is to use netcat. Open terminal, run **nc -l localhost 10000** and use `http.Post("http://localhost:10000", "application/json", buffer)`

Comment: You got it. Thank you very much. Tried it out with nc and got the correct results, so i must be doing it right. I guess what i saw in wireshark was the SYN request? Thanks for enlightening me!